# Setting up Android Studio for Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-studio, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I wrote a little `Hello World` program using `Android Studio`. Minimal sdk API is 16. I installed the virtual device running on API 21 and the program works fine. I also tried to run the program on a Galaxy S5 with Android 6 Cell phone which works fine.

I then connected my phone (Galaxy S2 with Jelly Bean) and tried to run it on the phone. However it only closed the app and displayed program closed.

[Here is the log shown by Android Studio](http://pastebin.com/RLRTJkyd)

And this is the Module:app build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "magu.schwaderina"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.0.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

The entire project directory can be found [here](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/1ce87be7cd82947d332ee10ad4fa190220160716142716/5b031e1a7f788da9a20a77cf154abd8820160716142716/57169c).Any help on were I go wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to mention I'm using Android Studio 2.2 Prev 5 on Ubuntu 14.4

Comment: Android studio is already set for every api version there is nothing like **Setting up Android Studio for Jelly Bean**..!!

Comment: can you post the error log from your android studio

Comment: @APPBird. The error log is linked as well as the entire project I can't directly paste them into the question since they are too long.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using v1.5.0 or below of the Gradle plugin, you need the following code in your app’s build.gradle:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Stops the Gradle plugin’s automatic rasterization of vectors
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  // Flag to tell aapt to keep the attribute ids around
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.njl8u0f91

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using Gradle version 2.1 and it automatically added the line `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` from your link, which is by the way a very nice read

Answer (score 0):

All the information is available in your log, please review it closely, and will discover your issue (related to Vector Drawable).  All the information is called out in the log (including line numbers, etc), so just follow the errors, which explain the issue you have.

Start at the bottom of your log and move up.  You will see that you have an issue with the Vector Drawables you are including, based on this message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{magu.schwaderina/magu.schwaderina.Main}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
```

Then if you move further up the stack, you will find other interesting tidbits, including:

```
E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <vector>
                  org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
                      at
```

Comment: While the information is there I'm still unable to act on it. Could you elaborate a bit on it?